# Why does OpenCv returns a false ret, frame=cap.read()?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm simply trying to get the image of my webcam in python with OpenCV 4.2.0 (on Spyder - python 3.7 running on windows 10). I just copy-pasted the code of the OpenCV documentation (see below) and most of the time it prints: "Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ..."
So I know the error comes from: ret, frame = cap.read(). But I don't know how to fix this.
Sometimes it prints: "Cannot open camera" and then it exits the Spyder Console and starts a new one
And sometimes it just works great...
Can anyone help?
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Added the last line to close the window

Comment: Without more details, it's really impossible to say. I'd strongly suggest tracing the actual OS-level syscalls underlying the failure. `strace` can do that with a really unpleasant amount of performance overhead; personally, I'd suggest [`sysdig`](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/). Wouldn't be at all surprised if this came down to the actual driver being used for the video capture, how it's being opened, what constraints apply around how many applications can be using the same device, etc.

Comment: Maybe you don't have a camera 0?

Comment: @beaker I do definitely have a camera 0 because sometimes it works... I've run the code 20 times and 10 out of the 20 times worked well, while the other 10 times didn't. It was always the same, it didn't work once and the next try it worked well, then it was stuck again. I also found that when there was a "ret" error and I ran the code again less than 5sec later, there was a "cap.isOpened" error followed by a "ret" error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What exactly does strace or sysdig do? I've never used it, so I don't know how to implement it in my code or how to use it. From the research I did, it works on Unix... Does it also work on windows? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know what the Windows equivalents are. Both tools trace the individual calls the program makes into the operating system, so you can see what it's asking the OS or its drivers for, and exactly what results or errors the OS is giving back. strace is an older/slower/more-widely-available (on Linux) approach; sysdig is a newer and *much* faster alternative... but neither will do data collection on Windows that I know of.

Comment: Hmmm... It almost sounds like cap isn't getting released, but I can see it right there. You might try writing a script that does nothing but open and release cap, and see if that makes the next run of your full script successful. Also, is 1ms long enough on `cv.waitKey`? I would expect there to be more time between successive frames.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (now for a while). I run Linux, not Windows. I read video feeds from multiple IP cameras, not just one webcam. But I believe the solution would be the same. In my opinion, it looks as if the feed, or OpenCv stops supplying frames. So I simply recreate cap, test ret, and move on. This will create a endless loop, it will never stop. In my scenario this correct. I want to real all frames, all the time.

It will look something like:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture('rtsp://1.2.3.4:554//Streaming/Channels/1')
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    while ret == False:
       print("Can't receive frame. Retrying ...")
       cap.release()
       cap = cv.VideoCapture('rtsp://1.2.3.4:554//Streaming/Channels/1')                                                                              
       ret, frame = cap.read()


    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print('frame')
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Doesn't seems like your script is working fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)# In place of zero we gonna use path of the video file.
 
    

while cap.isOpened():
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # if frame is read correctly ret is True
        if ret:
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv.imshow('frame', gray)
        

    
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
else:
        print("camer not streaming")
    
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).